# Clear WordPress Custom Transient Values

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've seen an article saying that in order to delete WordPress feed caches, the following code would work.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient%_feed_%')" );
```

So how do I apply this to my own transient caches?

If I save data like,

```
set_transient('mytransient_oneminutecache', $data1, 60);
set_transient('mytransient_onehourcache', $data2, 60 * 60);
set_transient('mytransient_12hourcache', $data3, 60 * 60 * 12);
```

Then does this work?

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient%mytransient_%')" );
```

Or should it be

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient%_mytransient_%')" );
```

?

I'm not used to view data base tables so if you can tell if it works or not or how to view inside the option table, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think I got it.

First I ran this

```
$data1 ='hi';
$data2 ='hello';
$data3 ='bye';

set_transient('mytransient_oneminutecache', $data1, 60);
set_transient('mytransient_onehourcache', $data2, 60 * 60);
set_transient('mytransient_12hourcache', $data3, 60 * 60 * 12);
```

Next opened, **http://[site address]/wp-admin/options.php**

then found these are saved:

> _transient_mytransient_12hourcache
>   _transient_mytransient_onehourcache
>   _transient_mytransient_oneminutecache
>
> _transient_timeout_mytransient_12hourcache
>   _transient_timeout_mytransient_onehourcache
>   _transient_timeout_mytransient_oneminutecache

So after that, I ran this and they were gone!

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient%_mytransient_%')" );
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient_timeout%_mytransient_%')" );
```

Comment: Better using `$wpdb->options` in case you're using a non standard table prefix.

Answer (score 0):

```
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` LIKE ('_transient%\\_mytransient\\_%')" );
```

is probably better because  an _ is a single-character wildcard so needs escaping .